# BASH Adding ServerName to Apache.conf via AWK

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to automate a build and deploy, and realized that I cannot get `ServerName` inserted correctly under

```
# Global configuration
#
```

for some silly reason awk isn't interpreting my `\n` If I remove `\n#` it works fine, but I would like it under the global comment instead of in the middle of it, what am I doing wrong here?

Hoping to see

```
# Global configuration
#

ServerName localhost
```

Here's the expression

```
awk '/# Global configuration\n#/ { print; print "\nServerName localhost"; next }1' apache2.conf
```

Maybe a better idea to just use SED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is for line by line processing. You can match a pattern contained in a singe line only.

What you're trying to do is can be done using:

```
awk '/# Global configuration/{c=1;print;next} c&&/^#/ {print; print "\nServerName localhost"; c=0; next} 1' file

# Global configuration
#

ServerName localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for the hard work! +1 and works perfectly, deff accepted. You sir, are the man!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
awk 'p&&!NF{print "ServerName localhost";p=0}/# Global configuration/{p=1}1' apache2.conf
```